# C Programming Looping with Row and Column

Tags: c, loops

Just try to learn and pick up the logic of C programming. I feel little bit confused for the looping to control the row and column

How can i achieve it in C ?

```
Enter the number: 3
-a-
---
-a-

Enter the number: 5
-a-a-
-----
-a-a-
-----
-a-a-
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what have you done so far ?

Comment: tell your logic one can help to build on your thinking

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a learning exercise, here are some points to get you on the path to a solution:

- The most common way of iterating in two dimensions is two nested loops
- In this situation, using two nested `for` loops would be a good idea
- Inside the body of the inner `for` loop you have access to two variables - one denoting the current row, and one denoting the current column
- Your code needs to decide if a letter or a dash is to be printed based on the values of the row and the column
- When the row is odd, or when the column is even, print a dash; otherwise, print character `'a'`
- You can tell if a number is odd or even by examining `num % 2` or `num & 1`. In both cases, if the result is zero, the number is even; otherwise, the number is odd.

Answer (score 0):

It is just about using nested loops, I would say if you want to learn specifics about accessing row and coloumn, practice some programs on Matrix operations such as addition, multiplication etc. You will find a lot of them in google.

Answer (score 0):

put this in your `gcc -o cloop cloop.c -std=c99` and `./cloop` it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char**argv){

   int i;
   do{
      i = 0;
      printf("Give me an int (0 to quit) ");
      if( scanf("%u", &i) != 1) break;
      if( i < 0 ) i = 0;
         for( int j =0; j<i;j++) {
               for( int k =0; k<i;k++)
                  printf("%s", (
                     k % 2 == 0
                     ? "-"
                     : j % 2 == 0 ? "a" : "-" )
                  );
         printf("\n");
      }
   } while ( i > 0 );
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what is being asked. Your program produces only one line insted on n lines.

Comment: whoops.  Well that's fixed now.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int i,j,n;
printf("Enter the number:");
scanf("%d",&n); // Input the number
for(i=0;i<n;i++) // For n rows
  {
     printf("\n");     // New line after each row
     for(j=0;j<n;j++) // For n columns for each row
         {
           if(i%2==0)      // For alternate(even) rows(the one with a's)
            {
              if(j%2==0)       // For alternate(even) columns(the one without a's)
              printf("-");
              else
              printf("a");
            }
           else
              printf("-");   // For alternate(odd) rows(with only -'s)
         }
 }
```

}

```
This is the logic.
```

Comment: That answer would be better if the code was properly indented.